# Is it possible to prepare store bought corn tortillas so they don't fall apart?

Tags: tortilla

Is it possible to prepare store bought corn tortillas so they don't fall apart? I know they are healthier than flour and they taste fine, but mine frequently fall apart to the point that it isn't a tortilla anymore.

If it is not possible, then can I make them at home myself so that they don't fall apart?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23532/67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just buying poorly-made tortillas, or old ones. A reasonably fresh corn tortilla is plenty sturdy for use in tacos or enchiladas. As they get older, they dry out and become more brittle. If you live in a place with a large Mexican population, you may be able to find a local tortilleria which makes fresh tortillas. Failing that, corn tortillas from the grocery store can be adequate as long as they're relatively fresh.

You can also make tortillas at home pretty easily using just corn flour (also known as masa, masa harina, or maseca), water, and a rolling pin. If you want to shape them more perfectly, or if you're going to be using lots of tortillas, you can get a tortilla press:

[image]

They are usually made of iron or wood and will let you press balls of masa dough into perfectly-flat tortillas.

Answer (score 1):

Corn tortillas lose their pliability very quickly.

You can restore some of their pliability with heat.

Microwaving the tortillas briefly will make them temporarily pliable. They may still crack when they cool, however.

The traditional approach is to dip the tortillas in hot oil. It's a little messy for me but it works very well and produces enchiladas that have the right texture.

Of course, if your tortillas are very old they may be stale and reheating them won't let them be pliable for long. There's nothing left for those but slicing and frying for corn chips.